# PyQt QDirModel does not show all folder in mac

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

I create a QDirModel, the start folder in the QDirModel is the root "/" , but the folders like "/Volumes", "/tmp" etc are not included. How can I can show all folders in the QDirModel?

[image]

```
class CheckableDirModel(QtWidgets.QDirModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDirModel.__init__(self, None)


class MainWindows(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindows, self).__init__()
        self.folder_model = CheckableDirModel()
        self.folder_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.folder_view.setModel(self.folder_model)
```

Comment: The `QDirModel` class is obsolete. Use [QFileSystemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) with an appropriate [filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter).

Comment: can you help me telling that how you created checkbox along every item without giving any definitions in class Checkable Model.I am working on windows.:-)

Comment: self.folder_model = CheckableDirModel()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder like "/Volumes", "/tmp" are hidden by the MACOS, so I do this to show them in the QDirModels:

```
self.folder_model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Hidden)
```